# How do I know what in my code is triggering this 'System.ObjectDisposedException ?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm debugging and enhancing a C#/XAML program that repeatedly generates an exception while running which I can see looking at the Output window.

**A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll**

**A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll**

(for some reason they seem to happen in pairs) The program itself keeps running after the exceptions occur.

The program consists of some XAML/C# code-behind which forms a front-end and test harness for a library of calls in a .Net DLL, which is also part of our C# code.
The total code-base (front end and DLL) is about 100K lines of C# source code code spread among about 25 files.    It mostly runs in one thread except for code which runs in socket-data handlers which get called by the system when data arrives from outside hardware devices (this program runs a factory manufacturing process).

How do I narrow-down/track-down where or what in my code is triggering these exceptions?

Comment: It means you are trying to access an object that has been disposed, either by an explicit `Dispose()` call, a `using` block, or by a containing object being disposed.  Without a stack trace and source code that's about all that can be inferred.

Comment: So how do I break on this exception so I can get a stack trace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can break execution when an exception is thrown. Go to debug menu -> exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> System -> System.ObjectDisposedException and check the checkbox for "Thrown".

Answer (score 2):

This exception indicates an attempt to access an object after it has been [`.Dispose()`-ed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx). The reason the program continues to run is that the exception is handled. a First-Chance exception is always generated when an exception is thrown, even if it is handled with a `catch` statement.

In general, many first chance exceptions like this are not something to worry about. If you want to track them down, you will need to attach a first chance exception handler, and then use the `StackTrace` Property to find them. Assuming your `Main` function is in `Program`, the following code should work

```
static Program()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, e) =>
    { // Breakpoint here
    };
}
```

This will give you access to the exception via the [`e.Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.firstchanceexceptioneventargs.exception(v=vs.110).aspx)